# Как сделать переменную по id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт для вывода ajax почтовых форм. Скрипт сделан так что бы можно было бы подключать несколько форм.
Но есть один нюанс когда делается запрос то должен приходить ответ 
в `<div id="fieldsop"> </div>` и  `<div id="noteop"> </div>`
но так получается что две формы могу быть на одной странице. И когда выполняешь запрос то ответ приходит на ближайший **id fieldsop** и **noteop**

как присвоить каждому **fieldsop** и **noteop** уникальный **+ strId +**
он в скрипте присутствует но я не пойму как это правильно применить.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".mailform2").submit(function() {
    var id = $(this)[0].id;
    var strId = id.replace(/^emai/, '');
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/mailpost" + strId + ".php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'OK') {
         result = '<div class="notification_ok"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;"></i>Спасибо! Наш менеджер с вами свяжится в ближайшее время.</div>';
          $("#fieldsop").hide();
        } else {
         result = msg;
        }
        $('#noteop').html(result);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Где в разметке находятся `fieldsop` и `noteop` по отношению к форме?

Comment: Получается `fieldsop` закрывает форму вставляя сообщения с переменной `result`, а `noteop` выводит сообщения об ошибках ну типа не ввел email

Comment: Это разве ответ на мой вопрос?

Comment: @Igor тогда я не понял ваш вопрос.
Рядом возле формы находится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколкьо понятно у вас есть ID `$(this)[0].id` для каждой формы и для каждой формы есть свой контейнер для результата, можно сделать так:

```
HTML /* как пример*/

<div id="fieldsop_ID1"> </div>
<div id="noteop_ID1"> </div>

<div id="fieldsop_ID2"> </div>
<div id="noteop_ID2"> </div>

<div id="fieldsop_ID3"> </div>
<div id="noteop_ID3"> </div>



JS

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".mailform2").submit(function() {
    var id = $(this)[0].id;
    var strId = id.replace(/^emai/, '');
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/mailpost" + strId + ".php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'OK') {
         result = '<div class="notification_ok"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;"></i>Спасибо! Наш менеджер с вами свяжится в ближайшее время.</div>';
          $("#fieldsop_"+id).hide();
        } else {
         result = msg;
        }
        $('#noteop_'+id).html(result);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: А если использовать `+strId`, получиться как вы думаете?

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko Какое значение у вас в strId?  надеюсь не эл.адрес  )))

Comment: нет) он служит для id ))

Comment: да можете. Не забудьте, каждый контейнер для результата должен иметь свой ID в зависемости к какой форме (к какому ID ) он относится

Comment: ну да так и есть.